# How to sort custom arraylist by object value integer

Tags: java, android, list, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList called ideas:

```
public ArrayList<Idea> ideas = new ArrayList<Idea>();
```

In the ideas class i have a private integer value called id.

```
private long id;
public long getId() {return id;}
```

How would you sort the ArrayList in ascending and descending values?

Comment: You need to have a custom comparator

Comment: This link may help you http://programtalk.com/java/sort-list-java/

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Collections.sort(list, comparator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-). Using this approach you don't need to edit your `Idea` class.

```
Collections.sort(ideas, new Comparator<Ideas>() {
    public int compare(Idea i1, Idea i2) {
        return i1 - i2;
    }
});
```

To use rever order you can use:

```
Collections.sort(ideas, (new Comparator<Ideas>() {
    public int compare(Idea i1, Idea i2) {
        return i1 - i2;
    }
}).reverseOrder());
```

Comment: See the discussion on @NikolasCharalambidis's answer. This approach suffers from the same issue.

Comment: I agree. Using `return Long.valueOf(i1.getId()).compareTo(i2.getId())` fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Sorting ArrayList example is given below according to your code

**SortIdeaExample.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SortIdeaExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Idea> ideaList = new ArrayList<Idea>();
        ideaList.add(new Idea(11l));
        ideaList.add(new Idea(2l));
        ideaList.add(new Idea(13l));
        ideaList.add(new Idea(4l));

        SortIdeaExample sortExample = new SortIdeaExample();
        System.out.println("Before sorting:" + ideaList);
        sortExample.sortList(ideaList);
        System.out.println("Ascending sorted list:" + ideaList);
        sortExample.sortListReverse(ideaList);
        System.out.println("Descending sorted list:" + ideaList);
    }

    private void sortList(List<Idea> list) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Idea>() {
            public int compare(Idea ideaVal1, Idea ideaVal2) {
                // avoiding NullPointerException in case name is null
                Long idea1 = new Long(ideaVal1.getId());
                Long idea2 = new Long(ideaVal2.getId());
                return idea1.compareTo(idea2);
            }
        });
    }

    private void sortListReverse(List<Idea> list) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Idea>() {
            public int compare(Idea ideaVal1, Idea ideaVal2) {
                // avoiding NullPointerException in case name is null
                Long idea1 = new Long(ideaVal1.getId());
                Long idea2 = new Long(ideaVal2.getId());
                return idea2.compareTo(idea1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Idea.java**

```
public class Idea {
    private long id;

    public Idea(long id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Idea [id=" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before sorting:[Idea [id=11], Idea [id=2], Idea [id=13], Idea [id=4]]
Ascending sorted list:[Idea [id=2], Idea [id=4], Idea [id=11], Idea [id=13]]
Descending sorted list:[Idea [id=13], Idea [id=11], Idea [id=4], Idea [id=2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty easily if you are using Java 8 with method pointers. Something like this should do the trick:

```
ArrayList<Idea> ideas = new ArrayList<Idea>();
ideas.sort(Comparator.comparing(Idea::getId));
ideas.sort(Comparator.comparing(Idea::getId).reversed());
```

If you are not using Java 8, I would use an anonymous class as mentioned by other answers.

Edit - Works with `long`. I see other answers having issues with `long`.

Comment: Succinct and clean! I didn't know about the `comparing()` method, and I was surprised that it worked even with `getId()` returning a `long` value. +1

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own comparator. Implement `Comparable` class to your `Idea` class. Then override `compareTo()` method. It would look like this:

```
public class Idea implements Comparable<Idea> {

   // Variables, constructor, getters, setters ...

   @Override
   public int compareTo(Idea other) {
      return Long.compare(this.getId(), other.getId());
   }
}
```

Finally sort with  `Collections.sort(list);`

If you want a reverse result, do this: `Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());`

Also note that the `compareTo()` method returns `int` even you want to compare `long`. That's why you have to use `Long.compare(...)`.

Comment: `id` is a `long`, not an `int`

Comment: The problem is that `Comparable`'s `compareTo()` method returns an `int`, but the `id` is a `long`.  Subtraction won't work. The comparison must be handled using relational operators (e.g. `==`, `>`,`<`)

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches. Either you can implement a custom `Comparator` or you can have `Idea` Implement the `Comparable<Idea>` interface. But you have to be careful: Since `id` is of type `long`, you cannot use subtraction as suggested by the other answers. The `compare()` and `compareTo()` methods return an `int`, but subtracting the `id`s yields a `long`. Instead, you'll have to compare the `id`s using the (less-concise) relational operations (e.g. `>`, `<`, `==`. Here's how you can accomplish this:

**Method 1:**

*In Java 8:* Since `Comparator` is Functional Interface, you can pass a lambda expression to the `ideas.sort()` method, as follows:

```
ideas.sort((i1,i2)->(i1.getId() < i2.getId()) ? -1 : ((i1.getId() == i2.getId()) ? 0 : 1));
```

*In pre-Java 8*: If you are using a version prior to Java 8, you use an annonymous `Comparator`:

```
ideas.sort(new Comparator<Idea>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(Idea i1, Idea i2) {
        (i1 < i2) ? -1 : ((i1 == i2) ? 0 : 1)
    }

});
```

**Method 2:**

Have the `Idea` class implement the `Comparable<Idea>` interface:

```
public class Idea implements Comparable<Idea>{
    private long id;

    public long getId(){
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Idea o) {
        (id < o.id) ? -1 : ((id == o.id) ? 0 : 1);
    }

}
```